# Wraping EditText Boxes in Layout

Tags: android, layout

I have a UI that has 6 EditText boxes.  3 of those EditText boxes don't show up when in vertical orientation.  I was hoping that wrap_content would wrap the non-showing 3 to the next line but found out that LinearLayout only allows for one row.

When in horizontal orientation I get all 6 of them showing.

I tried a TableView with two rows of 3 each.  That looks dorky when in horizontal orientation.

Do I need code to determine when the orientation changes to redraw those EditText boxes so it looks better or is there some layout that will automatically wrap when in vertical orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a layout with the same name and put it in res/layout-land.  It'll use that when in landscape mode.

Comment: synic, thanks.  I'm trying it but get "Multiple Marker" errors in the generated R.java file.  Do I need to rename all of the Spinners, EditText views etc so each file has unique names?

Answer (score 0):

u can determine the orientation by this 
this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation